# How to convert html templates to drupal 8?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

How to convert html templates  to drupal 8?
please help me step by step for how to convert html5 templates to drupal8.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom theme for that.

https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8